# Does anyone know what javascript graph library this is (or can recommend something similar)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph

I say this video and I want to implement something similar. I've seen a bunch of javascript graph libraries, but none that look exactly like this.

[Here is the video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNbppXGyCIE)

If not this, then something similar would be great. I'm especially interested in one that has highlight/zoom, value pop-ups, and is free/open source.

Comment: Tried [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at a new project called [Rickshaw.js](http://shutterstock.github.com/rickshaw/). It is opensource and licensed under MIT.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Highstock from the makers of Highcharts: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/

It's useful for much more than just stock charts, and performs the zooming that you are looking for.

It's free and open-source for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `Raphael.js`. It is free and open source. Link: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Does it do zoom? I can't find an example where it does.

Comment: You would have to play around with it. But you can make it zoom. I have seen examples

Comment: @Joehillen Raphael.js is a vector graphics library. You can implement a lot of things using it but it requires some work :). For graph-specific functionality see [g.raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).